# Winform Tooltip Control doesn't apply style on some computers

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I'm currently working on a c#/winform project, the winform contains a Tooltip that should have some custom style:

```
this.toolTip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.toolTip1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chartreuse;
```

But on my computer, the Tooltip doesn't have any of these properties, my groupmate does have this properties displayed properly.

I'm on Windows 8 , he's on windows 7 we both use Visual studio 2013.

If you guys have any idea...

Thanks.

EDIT: my mate tried to use W7 Aero Theme, tooltip's style doesen't applied anymore.
EDIT2: Just in case, i tried other colors, it doesn't work anyway, moreover, the colors i want to use work elsewhere in our project.

Comment: I've never fully looked at the settings but does your windows 8 have a windows basic theme? (i.e Windows aero turned off)

Comment: After googling a bit, Windows aero doesn't exist on W8, you can "fake enable" it with some tricks or a special software.
I'va tried to use my default w8 basic theme, doesen't work.
My mate is not using w7 Aero theme either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i finally found the problem, i add it in case someone's got the same problem.

As read the Doc once again, i understood that tooltips are drawn y the system if you dont set OwnerDraw to true.

BUT if IsBallon is set to true also, it will "override" the owned draw and use system to draw the tooltip so it will ake it's default style value.

I just removed IsBalloon and edited the Draw event.

Worked